# Web Design/CSS: Blurred text jitters when being "un-blurred" on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, blur

Please take a look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heLwx9bz/

I am trying to "un-blur" some text on hover, with a transition. Notice how the text slightly jitters when transitioning to `blur(0px)`, it jumps up and left by about 1px. Why is that and how can I avoid it? The jittering only occurs when a transition is added to the property change.

Here's code of my test case, very simple:

```css
p {
  font-size: 200px;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
  transition: 0.7s -webkit-filter;
}

.blur:hover {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="blur">
    TEST
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in firefox, but not in chrome. (The jitter effect is occuring due to the transition)

Comment: If any of the solution solved your query, it'd be appreciated to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a Google Chrome issue.**

> Certain css transitions will be hardware accelerated. What this means
>   is that they will use the power of your computers graphics card to
>   apply the transitions – and since the graphics card is optimized for
>   graphical effects, this makes the transitions much smoother.
>
> The thing is transitions don’t always use hardware acceleration, but
>   if you apply a specific css rule then they will force it to enable.
>   One of the css properties that will enable hardware acceleration is
>   the transform rules. So apply a css transform and the graphics card
>   does all the work.

Just add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the code and it will be fixed.

```css
p {
  font-size: 200px;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
  transition: 0.7s -webkit-filter;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.blur:hover {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="blur">
    TEST
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the solution with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` doesn't work for you try setting unblurred version to `filter: blur(.2px)`.

```css
p {
  font-size: 200px;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(2.5px);
  transition: 0.7s -webkit-filter;
}

.blur:hover {
  filter: blur(0.2px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="blur">
    TEST
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue. Test on chrome.